# Запись отметки в базу после клика по тизерам

Tags: php, javascript

Хотелось бы узнать, как передать данные о том, что пользователь нажал на тизеры. Тизеры берутся на тизернете. Нужно для того, чтобы сделать автоматическое отключение рекламы на сайте для определенного пользователя, когда он нажмет на рекламу.

Comment: Дайте ссылку посмотреть. Вообще не в теме, что есть тизер. ) Подозреваю, что-то типа "`onclick="sendRequest('teaserid=15');clickOnTeaser(this);"`"

Comment: Есть onclick="tnHidePopin(this, ' + p + ', ' + b + ')"

Answer (score 1):

Можно в функцию tnHidePopin дописать отправку ajax запроса на добавление данных в БД.